# Can an Actor peek at it's MessageQueue in Akka.net

Tags: akka.net

I have an IPClient actor which manages/owns a connection which is expensive to open/close.

Before the actor finishes handling a message, I'd like to peek at the top of the actor's Mailbox to check if there is another message pending.
 - If the actor has got more work, leave the connection open.
 - If the actor has emptied it's mailbox, close the connection.

Here's the gist of what i'm thinking:

```
public void Handle(PollDevice message)
    {
        if (!_client.IsConnected)
            _client.Connect();

        var results = _client.GetData()

        var actorHasMoreWork = Context.Dispatcher.Mailboxes.???
        if (!actorHasMoreWork)
            _client.Disconnect();

        Sender.Tell(true);
    }
```

Is this possible? Is it the best way?

Comment: Does _client have state specific to this actor? Wondering if you could just use pooled connections where you have a pool of actors that keep open connections and this actor in the example forwards messages to them

Comment: Just happened upon this question and was wondering if you were able to peek at the mailbox?  (Hmm, I think I saw that there used to be a PeekMailbox that was something else - let you pull the next message from the mailbox without removing it - but it got deprecated.)  I was just going to say that my working-with-what-I-know solution to this would have been to leave the connection open by default but have the actor send a simple...

Comment: ...message to itself at the end of your method (while also keeping an instance-level reference to the message).  If that just-sent message was the next message received, there was clearly nothing in the queue, so go ahead and close the connection.

Answer (score 3):

I have a partial answer.

You can get an actor's mailbox's ID (but not the mailbox itself) with `Context.Props.Mailbox`

And once you have an actor's mailbox (which, again, the previous step will not give you), my understanding of the documentation says you should be able to use either `Mailbox.MessageQueue.HasMessages` or `Mailbox.MessageQueue.Count` to get information about the contents. As far as I can tell, you would not be able to see any of the messages without dequeuing them.

I have not been able to determine a way to get the Mailbox object, however, and I've actually found some evidence it is not currently possible in Akka.Net. There is [a GitHub issue about making this possible](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/383) that's been open since September 2014, and the last update is also from September 2014.

Comment: Actually the GitHub issue was updated in November 2018 with code to retrieve the mailbox size: https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/383#issuecomment-436523926